# How to fix /usr/local/bin/virtualenv: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory?

Tags: python, virtualenv

When I tried to use virtualenv on Ubuntu 18.04, I got this error:

> bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenv: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Python 2 and 3 is working fine:

```
josir@desenv16:~/bin$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
josir@desenv16:~/bin$ python3
Python 3.6.9 (default, Apr 18 2020, 01:56:04) 
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
```

I've already tried to unistall virtualenv:

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove virtualenv
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove python-virtualenv
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove python3-virtualenv
```

But when I installed again, the error remains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenv: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

The error is in '/usr/**local**/bin/virtualenv' — it's first line ([shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))) is `#!/usr/bin/python` and there is no such file at your system.

I believe the stream of events led to the situation is: you've installed `virtualenv` with `pip` (not `apt`) long ago and put `/usr/local/bin` at the front of your `$PATH`. Then you upgraded you system; the upgrade removed `/usr/bin/python`, now you have only `/usr/bin/python3`.

Now you have to decide which route you'd go: `apt` or `pip`. If you choose `apt` — remove `/usr/local/bin/virtualenv`.

If you choose `pip`: my advice is to uninstall as much as possible python packages installed with `apt`; reinstall `virtualenv`; that should be the only additional package installed with `apt`. For every project/task create a virtual environment and install packages with `pip`.

PS. Personal experience: I switched from `apt` way to `pip` a few years ago.

PPS. Avoid using `sudo pip` — do not clobber system installation. Either install into virtual environments or `pip install --user`.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you for an incredibly useful explanation that saved me even further frustration and lost time. This answer deserves more votes!

Answer (score -1):

Installing via debian packages created me errors in the past. The solution to your problem is using pip:

```
sudo pip3 install virtualenv
```

Full tutorial here: [How to install virtualenv for Python3 on Linux](https://gist.github.com/Geoyi/d9fab4f609e9f75941946be45000632b)